# Twitter typeahaed.js - Change query source when certain characters are hit

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

I'm using [typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) and would like to use a local array for the typeahead if the user has typed 3 or less characters, and then fall back onto a remote query if typing more than that. How can I implement an `if` statement in the `source` option of the typeahead? Below is my code now, but it's not working as intended. The source doesn't seem to like this method. When I call `localTypeaheadData` it doesn't get returned properly to the source.

```
var localTypeaheadData = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  local: localArray
});

$('#sitesearch').typeahead({
    minLength: 1,
},
{
    name: 'sitesearch',
    source: function (query, process) {
    if (query.length < 4) {
        return localTypeaheadData;
    } else {
        return remoteTypeaheadData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't straight forward in the examples and the documentation left me hanging but I figured it out using the following code.

```
var localTypeaheadData = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  local: localArray
});

function searchData(query, sync, async) {
    if (query.length < 4) {
        localTypeaheadData.search(query, sync);
    } else {
        // something else
    }
}

$('#sitesearch').typeahead({
    highlight: true
},
{
    name: 'sitesearch',
    source: searchData
});
```